# Estimating the average value in a range of the normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have the average value of the red area and the average value of the green area below.  I also have the mean of the distribution and the value of X1 (in units, not a Z score as I know nothing about the standard deviation).  How do I estimate the average values in the red and green areas if I move the dividing line to X2?

[image]

Comment: Without knowing the standard deviation, I don't think you can say anything.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the average value of the red area"?

Comment: I meant the weighted average value or the expected value of all the observations that fall in that area of the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know three things $X_1$, $\mu_{\text{green}_1}$ and $\mu_{\text{red}_1}$.

You do not yet know $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for the whole distribution.

To find these, here are two equations using the density and distribution functions of a standard normal:

$$\mu_{\text{green}_1} = \mu + \dfrac{\phi\left(\dfrac{X_1 -\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{1-\Phi\left(\dfrac{X_1 -\mu}{\sigma}\right)}\sigma$$

$$\mu_{\text{red}_1} = \mu - \dfrac{\phi\left(\dfrac{X_1 -\mu}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\dfrac{X_1 -\mu}{\sigma}\right)}\sigma$$

You need to solve these two as simultaneous equations for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (I would use numerical methods).  You can then use the same equations again changing the subscripts from $1$ to $2$.

So as an example, if $X_1=1000$,  $\mu_{\text{green}_1}=1020$ and $\mu_{\text{red}_1}=990$ then you may find $\mu \approx 1013.361$ and 
$\sigma \approx  17.401$.

Then if $X_2=980$ this would suggest $\mu_{\text{green}_2} \approx 1014.497$ and $\mu_{\text{red}_2}\approx 973.337$

Comment: I know the mean of the distribution so I already know mu right?

Comment: @user3390169: You did not say you knew $\mu$ when I started answering the question - now you run the risk of having over-specified the problem.  But essentially the same thing works

Answer (score 1):

If by "average value in the red/green area" you mean the conditional expected values of $X$ given $X < X_1$ and given $X > X_1$, in principle you may be able to find $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from those.  I don't think there is a closed form solution, but you can try to solve numerically.

For example, suppose $X_1 = 2$, $E[X \mid X < X_1] = 1$ and $E[X \mid X > X_1] = 4$.  You are thus trying to solve the equations
$$ \dfrac{{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {{\mu}^{2}-4\,\mu+4}{{2\sigma}^{2}}}}}\sqrt {2/\pi}
\sigma+{\rm erf} \left({\frac {\sqrt {2} \left( \mu -2\right) }{2
\sigma}}\right)\mu-\mu
}{  -1+{\rm erf} \left({\frac {\sqrt {2} \left( \mu -2\right) }{2\sigma}}\right) 
}=1$$
$$\dfrac{{{\rm e}^{-{\frac {{\mu}^{2}-4\,\mu+4}{{2{\sigma}}^{2}}}}}
\sqrt {2/\pi}\;{\sigma}+{\rm erf} \left({\frac {\sqrt {2} \left( 
\mu-2 \right) }{2{\sigma}}}\right)\mu+\mu
}{  {\rm erf} \left({\frac {\sqrt {2} \left( 
\mu-2 \right) }{{2\sigma}}}\right)+1 
} = 4$$
According to Maple's fsolve command, the solution is
$$ \mu =  = 3.336132593, \sigma = 1.740103339$$

You can then use these values to calculate $E[X \mid X < X_2]$ and $E[X \mid X > X_2]$.